# SQL Server connection issues out of the blue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, vba, database-connection

So,

I have an app that connects to SQL Server (C#) app. I have made no changes that I can think of to the server or workstation but suddenly the app cannot connect (timeout error). Connecting using some VBA/excel code works fine and running the C# app on the server (but using the same connection string as on the workstation) works just fine. I tried to just connect to the DB using a simple C# program and again same error.

The connection string is identical in VBA and in C# except VBA has Provider=SQLOLEDB in it.

I tried restarting all machines, restarting SQL Server etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps try running a sniff during connection to see if there are differences between SQLOLEDB connection method and whatever you are using in C#.  It's possible the network admin did something to block??

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try this. I am not sure on the network admin. The local network is entirely mine and under my control but I am part of a turn-key office suite so maybe they did something? Could poor connectivity be a factor? (Despite the excel VBA connections working fine and the network as a whole working fine (and pinging the server/sqlserver name works fine)

Comment: doesn't sound like poor network connectivity in general - it wouldn't discriminate between the two types of connections.  if anything its going to be a firewall or custom routing issue.  if you have direct connectivity to your server via routers/switches under your control then it's less likely.  but as mrdenny says - back to basics.  imo, that means checking from the bottom up.

Answer (score 2):

Time to go back to basics.  From the workstation can you connect to the SQL Server port with telnet?  What provider is the VBA using?  What provider is the C# using?